# Trying to run optipng and jpegoptim on my linux dedicated server using putty

Tags: linux, shell, optimization, putty

I have successfully installed optipng and jpegoptim but trying to optimize directory and its not working

I'm trying to run this code

> jpegoptim -d/home/user/folder/images -name *.jpg

Answer (score 1):

"its not working" is not an error message, please post the actual output with the error message, but looking at the manpage I gather that `-name` is not an option.
Try:

```
find /path/to -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|jpeg\)" -exec jpegoptim -d/home/user/folder/images '{}' \+
```

Comment: this is what i got after using your code
`jpegoptim: skipping special file: *.jpg`

Comment: Perhaps jpegoptim can only whork on one file at a time. See my edit.

Comment: one file at a time? i have like 100k images on my server and apparently it works with directory as well but not sure what's exact command, I tried to run 'find /home/user/images -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|jpeg\)" -exec jpegoptim -d/home/user/images '{}' \+' and return was loop of all the images on server, something like this '/home/user/images/1.jpg 100x100 24 bit N JFIF [OK] jpegoptim: target file already exist:/home/user/images/1.jpg' ..to.... 'home/user/images/100,000.jpg...........'

Comment: yes and the result was "find: `/path/to': No such file or directory"

Comment: yes thats what im saying. when i put my own path, the result was infinite loop of all the images i have on my server `home/user/images/1.jpg 100x100 24 bit N JFIF [OK] jpegoptim: target file already exist:/home/user/images/1.jpg' ..to....   `home/user/images/100,000.jpg...........g`

Comment: Got `jpegoptim: skipping special file: *.jpg` for files that are not found, so may be worth to double check the path.

Answer (score 1):

Following command will find all jpegs within images path and execute jpegoptim to optimise these images:

```
find /path/to/images/ -type f -iname *.jpg -exec jpegoptim --max=60 --all-progressive -p {} \;
```

In Your case you can replace path and use following command:

```
find /home/user/folder/images/ -type f -size +1000k -iname *.jpg -exec jpegoptim --max=60 --all-progressive -p {} \;
```